# Remove VCF attachments (Business Card)

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2016

We were testing adding business cards to outlook emails, and now it always attaches the VCF file. I tried removing the business card from the signature, but the VCF file is still attached. I know that if I delete my signature, and create a new one, the VCF files will be removed. My question is, is there anyway to remove that VCF file without deleting the signature?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can delete the vcf attachment from the signature file:

1. Navigate to:

C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Signatures

2. Open the file folder which contains the vcf attachment of the signature:
   [image]
3. Delete the CVF file:

[image]